# Android: Change timezone of date string

Tags: android, timezone

I've been trying this for about an hour now but it doesn't seem to be working properly.

I'm basically reading a date string from a database, it's in the format yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss (2012-03-01 14:32:00).

At this point all I have is the string, no timezone info. This time is created on our server, and eventually gets into the device database, I know for a fact that it's Eastern Standard Time.

So I basically tried the following code:

```
SimpleDateFormat sourceFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"); 
        sourceFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST"));

        Date parsed = sourceFormat.parse("2012-03-01 10:18:14"); 

        TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault(); 
        SimpleDateFormat destFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"); 
        destFormat.setTimeZone(tz);  

        String result = destFormat.format(parsed);

        Log.v("TZ", result);
```

My emulator is EST so when I log the time it shows 2012-03-01 10:18:14, which is correct.

But if I change the time zone of sourceFormat to say America/Los Angeles I get an output of 2012-03-01 05:18:14.

Now I'm not an expert but I'm pretty sure Los Angeles is 3 hours behind Montreal (EST where our office is located). So if I take the time 2012-03-01 10:18:14 and call it America/Los Angeles time, then convert that to EST I expect to see 2012-03-01 13:18:14.

What's happening?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you able to test on a real device? Sometimes emulator doomed.

Comment: Yes I'm able to test on a device, I'll try that out as soon as I get in tomorrow. I understand that the emulator doesn't always behave like the real thing but it does show the current time as it is on my desktop.

Answer (score 1):

If you have not yet solved this, the use of three-letter time zone IDs (such as, in your case, "EST") has been deprecated from JDK 1.2 because the same abbreviation is often used for multiple time zones (for example, "CST" could be U.S. "Central Standard Time" and "China Standard Time"), and the Java platform can then only recognize one of them. So, even when you provide `sourceFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST"));`, the code defaults your timezone to GMT.

To avoid this, you may try replacing the 3-letter zone IDs with -
the **General time zone** format : `sourceFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-05:00"));`,

or the **RFC 822 time zone** format : `sourceFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("-05"));`.